# Angular wait for variable change

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make something actions in function only when variable is true.
This `changeAddressPermision` variable changes in popup - when user click cancel `changeAddressPermision` is false, and when user click confirm `changeAddressPermision` is true. Popup looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!isPopupClosed" class="popup">
    <p class="popup__text">Are you sure you want to change address?</p>
    <div class="popup-button__div">
        <button class="popup__button" (click)="isPopupClosed = true; changeAddressPermision = true">Yes</button>
        <button class="popup__button" (click)="isPopupClosed = true; changeAddressPermision = false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should work like this:
Function x listen to variable change - if user click Yes - popup close and function x do something based on `changeAddressPermision`. It should wait for user click on popup and if user click something - its do something based if `changeAddressPermision == false or true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding setter/getter for `changeAddressPermision` like the following:

```js
set changeAddressPermision(value: boolean) {
    this._changeAddressPermision = value;

    if (value) {
        // do something here if value is true
    } else {
        // do something here if value is false
    }
}
get changeAddressPermision(): boolean {
    return this._changeAddressPermision;
}
private _changeAddressPermision: boolean;
```